# Google Apps Script IP Address

Tags: google-apps-script

i did create an App with Google Apps Script. I allow this IP range in my App: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#accessing

But since last week i get always an error because i have a IP that i do not allow to access my App.

Example:
107.178.192.106

I tried to find out from which country/city is this IP Address: Its from Mountain View.

Is the IP Range in the developers site out of the date?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

There are pages like [this](https://www.whoismyisp.org/ip/107.178.192.106) or [this](https://www.iplocation.net/) or [this](http://www.ip2location.com/demo) that will give you varying amounts of detail depending on the country, ISP, etc.

Looks like that IP is owned by Google Drive in [Mountain View](https://www.google.ca/maps/place/37%C2%B024'47.9%22N+122%C2%B009'04.7%22W), California and is possibly assigned to someone from [Danville](https://www.google.ca/maps/place/39%C2%B045'38.2%22N+86%C2%B031'35.0%22W), Indiana and/or [Ashburn](https://www.google.ca/maps/place/39%C2%B002'37.7%22N+77%C2%B029'14.6%22W), Virginia.  The accuracy of the coordinates depend on a few factors and are unlikely to be exact.  In my area, the point to the nearest "repeating startion" of my DSL ISP, so within a few blocks of my home.